# Neo4j - Limiting the number of nodes while retrieving using Scala/Java API

Tags: java, scala, neo4j, graph-databases

Say that I have 1000 article nodes. Am able to get all the article nodes in 1 pull with the code below

```
val articles = ArticleIndex.query("article_id","*").iterator()
```

But, I need to limit the no of nodes to 100 per pull. How do I do that using Scala/Java API?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Cypher to **limit** the results:

```
START n=node:article_index('article_id:*')
RETURN n
LIMIT 100
```

If you want the next 100 results, use the **SKIP** clause:

```
START n=node:article_index('article_id:*')
RETURN n
SKIP 100
LIMIT 100
```

Check out the [neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html) for the cypher execution syntax.

Comment: Can I do the above with Scala/Java API ?

Comment: Yes, see added documentation link.

Comment: Haven't worked with scala, but [Neo4j's website](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/scala) shows you the possibilities.

Comment: I'd prefer java though, as it's natively supported.